# How do I remove empty nav tag in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, navigation

Hello I would like to know how do i remove empty nav tag in the navigation bar. 
http://abraham-accountants.co.uk/

Comment: you could use css: display: none;

Comment: after contact page nav tab

Comment: As per my comment on your other question, links that entirely rely on external links are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Admin Panel` -> `Appearance` -> `Menus`

You can drag out the empty navbar element from the menu location, in your case I guess Main menu or Header menu.

**EDIT**
After comments discussion

Use the below code as Custom CSS.

```
#mainnav { background: transparent !important; }
```

Comment: where do i find it in menus section

Comment: There is no nav tab. There is only a closing </nav> tag.

Comment: Thank you where should i add it in my css code like

Comment: You can install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css and add it.